# Term for a Class with Multiple Interfaces

Tags: terminology, naming, interfaces, multiple-inheritance

Say I have a class that implements multiple interfaces. I pass the same instance around using a different interface, depending on what the consumer is interested in.

I am trying to remember what this is called. I know there is a fancy name for it - I thought it was "interface partitioning", but I'm not finding any hits. The official name and perhaps a link to a site explaining what it is would be handy.

In case I haven't explained myself well enough, here is a real world example. I have a class, call it `ContextManager`, that is responsible for providing access to configuration settings, session variables, user information and other utilities. Instead of passing the object around as a `ContextManager`, I might pass it around as an `IConfigurationManager` in one spot and as a `IUserManager` in another. This prevents the client from accessing things they shouldn't care about and allows me to reuse code within the class.

I just want to know what it is called?

Comment: You're not thinking of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) are you?

Comment: @paul No. I was sure there was a term specifically for splitting a class out into multiple interfaces for the purpose of limiting how other classes could use it.

Comment: Are you talking about [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)?

Comment: No. This *is* an example of multiple inheritance. So it's definitely related, but I am looking for the term when it is used specifically for limiting access to a large class.

Comment: God Object? (kidding aside, multiple interfaces can be a smell that single responsibility is being violated)

Comment: @Telastyn I'd usually agree with you. My example is a very special case. It's just this high-level object that provides access to a lot of environment information. In ASP.NET, most of this information comes from the `HttpContext`, which is itself a God Object. This approach is a way to protect the rest of the system from these holy ones.

Comment: This sounds like it might be related to the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) - maybe this will spark your memory.

Comment: It's called "a class that implements multiple interfaces."  Not everything on the planet needs a fifty-cent word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're describing the [facet pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FacetPattern), which is used to restrict an interface to obtain a smaller interface that provides less authority.  Inheriting multiple interfaces is one common way to implement this pattern.

This is related, but not identical, to the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), which is the 'I' in SOLID.  That principle states that no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.  The facet pattern is a way to adapt that principle to a large class.  However, there are other more common ways to follow the interface segregation principle, such as creating smaller classes.

Comment: I'm struggling to accept your answer. @shakedown's answer is actually what I was looking for but I am not seeing a distinction.

Comment: @TravisParks: I believe the distinction between the Facet Pattern and the ISP is the former has a god interface and the latter doesn't.

Comment: @shakedown Agreed. I have a hard time believing one of the SOLID principles would involve God classes.

Comment: @Travis, since Shakedown apparently declined to create his own answer, I have incorporated his comment into mine.